# What are the differences between traceview and hugo(a plugin)？

Tags: android, android-studio

'Hugo' is a plugin in android studio which uses annotation to print out runtime of functions(this 'hugo' is different from another 'Hugo' written by go language).Either 'hugo' or 'traceview' i have used,but i haven't found the essential difference between them.Or,they don't have essential difference??

Answer (score 0):

Using hugo

> As a programmer, you often add log statements to print method calls, their arguments, their return values, and the time it took to execute. This is not a question. Every one of you does this. Shouldn't it be easier?

Simply add @DebugLog to your methods and you will automatically get all of the things listed above logged for free.

Using TraceView

> Traceview is a graphical viewer for execution logs that you create by using the Debug class to log tracing information in your code. Traceview can help you debug your application and profile its performance.

It seems the biggest difference is the graphical viewer that Trace view provides. Hugo uses the annotation processor to generate code to track arguments, time it took to execute just like in ButterKnife.